# R - How to draw an empty plot with no height?

Tags: r, plot

I can make an empty plot in R by using:

```
plot.new()
```

That create a blank plot with the default width and height.

I want to create an empty plot with minimal height. I tried `png('z.png', height=1)`, but that got me:

```
> png('x.png', height=1)
> plot.new()
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

How can I create such a plot? I guess I have to zero the margins too.

Comment: Could you add some detail describing what you are trying to do with this?  The question in its current form leaves me confused about why anyone would ever want this to work.

Comment: The plot goes straight to a website, and I don't want it to occupy any space when there is an error. I'm managing errors in another level (make).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... I don't know why you would want to do this, but here goes:

```
# Make a png file
png('x.png', height=1)

# Change the margins of the plot to 0 on each side
par(mar=rep(0,4))

# Make an empty plot
plot.new()

# Close the connection to the png file
dev.off()
```

Comment: Perfect!

I tried something similar before, my mistake was calling par() before png().